# Changing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

i tried to construct a RewriteRule in my `.htaccess` to get a more pretty URL for displaying a thread forum using Zend Framework.
Target URL is:

```
/forum/display/thread/i/1
```

What I want:

```
/forum/display/thread/1
```

Since Zend Framework builds GET Variabels from the URL (in this case beginning after `/thread/`) my original URL gives me a GET variable `'i' = 1`, and the second URL gives me no GET variabels at all.

What I want, is either a way, to get the `/1` into a GET variable respecting, that there may be more coming (e.g. `/p/2` for the page number) OR a way to rewrite the URL using `mod_rewrite` so that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is set to `/forum/display/thread/i/1`.

Anybody has an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRouter()  
{  
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(  
        '/forum/display/thread/(.+?)',  
        array('controller' => 'forum', 'action' => 'display'),  
        array(1 => 'thread'),  
        '/forum/display/thread/%d'  
    );  
    $front->getRouter()->addRoute('routeName', $route);  
}
```

The code is not tested, please post any erros if they occure :)

Comment: I needed to modify your answer a bit for testing. its now:

    `private static function _setupRouter(Zend_Controller_Front $fc) {
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            'forum/display/t/(.+?)',
            array('module' => 'forum', 'controller' => 'display', 'action' => 'thread'),
            array('i' => 1)
        );
        $fc->getRouter->addRoute('routeName' $route);
    }`


now i get the following error:

Comment: `Cannot assemble. Reversed route is not specified.
#0 /library/Zend/Controller/Router/Rewrite.php(470): Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex->assemble(Array, false, true)
#1 /library/ViewRenderer.php(131): Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite->assemble(Array)`



sry for the bad formatting. I can't get it to display the code in a propper block